# Start a minute counter for every newly added item

Tags: java, jquery, counter

I am developing a website where the users will add items they want to sell.

I am now trying to figure out a way how to place a munite counter for every newly added item. I need the counter to start from 0 and count every minute the item has been active. I also need the counter to reset at the end of every month and start again from 0 in the beginning of the next month.

Do you have any suggestions where I can start from? 
I will appreciate any help here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do it base on a timestamp set in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would store the creation date inside a database and derive the number of minutes it has been available from it. If you're going to store a counter in memory things won't scale, apart from the fact that in case of failure you would lose all information.

Comment: Creation date will not work for this particular case as I need to add later on additional functionality like the counter to stop and start if the ad is being deactivated/activated from the user.

Comment: @user2891571 Yes it can work; if you are pausing and resuming later than you can change the creation date to the resume time; thus forgetting the original creation time. If you want to stop it completely (forever), you may store an additional date which signals the time it was stopped (by default this should be null). Storing deletion date would allow you to know the duration of the last active period.

Comment: Ok, this might work but it creates another problem. I will also have a separate function calulating the real time sum from all item counters. If an item is being deleted, how can i save and remember the value of the time duration at the deletion date to the total time?